# How to trigger MainActivity map modifications on RecyclerView items change

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have a RecyclerView which displays items on a map. Some of these items have location present and I would like to set markers on the map for them. Once the user scrolls and the item is no longer visible, I will remove the marker and then add the new ones where possible.

Here is my map fragment initialisation:

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

In here I initialize the map:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }
```

a Marker can be added as such:

```
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
   .title("Marker in Sydney"));
```

And I this is how to get the first and last visible items:

```
LinearLayoutManagerlayoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

and based on this I'd control which markers are shown.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to link all of them together. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is Your list and map are shown together or both of them are in different fragments or activity and either one of them is shown at a time. (Map or list)

Comment: I have the list and map in the MainActivity. And then in OnCreate I initialize the RecyclerView's Adapter with the list. They are both shown in the same activity, the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot asses your problem completely. but if it lies among these case.

1. both map and recycle view lie in same screen, That implies that user
   can see the list as well as map at the same time.
2. List and Map are two different section and are shown in two diffrent
   fragment or activities.That implies that user can see either the map
   or the list at a time.

**Case 1) If first is the case.**  - Use addOnScrollListener to get the updated position each time you
   scroll the list

```
 mRecyclverViewEvent.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override


     public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            updateMapMarker();
        }
    })
```

- Make an updateMapMarker() method, Remove the old markers and User the first and last visible item position to draw new marker on the map.First and last visible item position will allow you get the position to begin and to end from the Main list of items.

Comment: Case 1 it is. Thank you. I think the scroll listener is exactly what I was looking for. I ll let you know how it goes.

Comment: have you checked it?

Comment: Yes, it does seem to do the job. I just have to add some markers for the first items as the scroll will only trigger after it s been scrolled xD. Do you think that adding markers and removing them at a fast rate will result in slow-performance issues?

Comment: Although Considering that you are showing map and list on the same screen, A very few marker will be visible at the same time(Depends on screen size). you will never be dealing with a lot of markers removal and addition.we can improve it in following ways
1)Work on newState Variable it returns three states of scroll (idle, drag, settling)
2)List can be maintained in such a way that only those markers are added that are new  and only those are removed which are not visible in the list anymore. hence a intersection has to be found for those marker that has to be shown from previous list too

Comment: Yeah. I did exactly that. It doesn't seem to have any problems. Thank you.